# Loop methodn not giving accurate resuts

Tags: c#, loops, artificial-intelligence

I have created file during the runtime process John.txt and there are properties for John. The text of the file is "friend,banker" but when I execute and ask the AI "where is John"? it doesnt return any results despite I wrote the method `MatchProffesionWithProperties`. Where Am I wrong?

```
namespace Machine
{
    class Program
    {

        static bool HavingGreeted = false;

        static string person;

        static Dictionary<string, string> KeyValuePairs;

        static void MatchProffesionsWithProperties(string person,DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
        {
            var strings = File.ReadAllLines(person + ".txt");

            foreach(var stringi in strings)
            {
                var whitespacearray = stringi.Split(' ');

                var commaarray = stringi.Split(',');

                foreach(var property in whitespacearray)
                {
                    if (KeyValuePairs.ContainsKey(property))
                    {
                        if (dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday || dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday || dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday || dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday || dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} should be at the {1}", person, KeyValuePairs[property]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                foreach(var property in commaarray)
                {
                    if (KeyValuePairs.ContainsKey(property))
                    {
                        if (dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday || dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday || dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday || dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday || dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} should be at the {1}", person, KeyValuePairs[property]);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        static void ProcessQuestionForPerson(string word)
        {
            var array = word.Split(' ');

            if (word.Contains("Wh"))
            {
                person = array[2].Substring(0,array[2].Length-1);

            }
            else
            {
                person = array[1];
            }

            if (!File.Exists(person+".txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Who is {0}?", person);

                string data = Console.ReadLine();

                var filestream = File.Create(person + ".txt");

                byte[] b = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                filestream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);

                filestream.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                if (word.StartsWith("Who"))
                {
                    string data = File.ReadAllText(person + ".txt");

                    Console.WriteLine("{0} is a {1}", person, data);

                }
                if (word.StartsWith("Where"))
                {
                    MatchProffesionsWithProperties(person, DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
                }
            }


        }

        static void Greet(int hour)
        {
            if (hour > 0 && hour < 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good Morning");
            }
            if (hour > 12 && hour < 17)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good Afternoon");

            }
            if (hour > 17 && hour <= 23)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good Evening");
            }
        }


        static void ProcessQuestionForMyself(string word)
        {
            var array = word.Split(' ');

            //Process the components of the sentence

            string type = array[1];

            // get the type of the sentence

            string value = array[3].Substring(0,array[3].Length-1);

            // get the value of the sentence

            string questiontype = array[3].Substring(0,array[3].Length-1);

            //get the type of the question

            if (word.EndsWith("."))
            {
                string correctvalue = File.ReadAllText(type+".txt");

                // read from file the correct value

                if (type == "name")
                {
                    if (correctvalue == GetLowerUpper(value)[0] || correctvalue == GetLowerUpper(value)[1])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Correct.My name is {0}.", value);

                        // print response
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} is not my name.", value);

                        // print response
                    }
                }
                if (type == "age")
                {
                    if (correctvalue == value)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Correct.I am {0} years old.", value);

                        // print response
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} is not my age.", value);

                        // print response
                    }
                }

            }
            if (word.EndsWith("?"))
            {
                string answer = File.ReadAllText(questiontype+".txt");

                Console.WriteLine(answer);
            }

        }


        static string[]  GetLowerUpper(string word)
        {
            string upperword = word.Replace(word[0].ToString(), word[0].ToString().ToUpper());

            string lowerword = word.ToLower();

            //Create strings for answer and question0


            string[] array = new string[2] { upperword, lowerword };

            return array;
        }

        static void MainThread()
        {
            if (HavingGreeted == false)
            {
                Greet(DateTime.Now.Hour);

                HavingGreeted = true;
            }


            string data = Console.ReadLine();


            if (data.Contains(GetLowerUpper("your")[0]) || data.Contains(GetLowerUpper("your")[1]))
            {
                //Append to me

                ProcessQuestionForMyself(data);

            }

            if (!data.Contains("your"))
            {
                //Append to someone else

                ProcessQuestionForPerson(data);
            }


            // Repeat thread

            Thread repeatmainthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MainThread));

            repeatmainthread.Start();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            KeyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            KeyValuePairs.Add("Banker", "Bank");

            Thread mainthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MainThread));

            mainthread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result would be the AI to tell me that John should be at the bank.

Comment: If anybody of you watches Person of Interest , yes I am trying to replicate the Machine.

Answer (score 1):

`KeyValuePairs.ContainsKey(property)` is case-sensitive, so "banker" will not match "Banker". You can allow case-insensitive searching by changing the initialisation of `KeyValuePairs` to:

```
KeyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Changing `ProcessQuestionForPerson` to still ask a "Where is ..." question after creating a new file for that person:

```
static void ProcessQuestionForPerson(string word)
{
    var array = word.Split(' ');
    bool fileExisted = false;

    if (word.Contains("Wh"))
    {
        person = array[2].Substring(0,array[2].Length-1);
    }
    else
    {
        person = array[1];
    }

    fileExisted = File.Exists(person+".txt");

    if (!fileExisted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Who is {0}?", person);

        string data = Console.ReadLine();

        var filestream = File.Create(person + ".txt");

        byte[] b = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        filestream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);

        filestream.Close();
    }

    if (word.StartsWith("Who") && fileExisted)   //We don't want to answer "Who" when we've just answered it ourselves (remove && fileExisted if you do)
    {
        string data = File.ReadAllText(person + ".txt");

        Console.WriteLine("{0} is a {1}", person, data);
    }

    if (word.StartsWith("Where"))
    {
        MatchProffesionsWithProperties(person, DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty much only enough to be about to get that method running on my machine (with "Where" instead of "where"). :-)

Comment: `ProcessQuestionForPerson` may also need changing, especially if you're deleting the John.txt each time you run the program. If the file doesn't exist, it will create one for that person but won't answer the question.

Comment: Yes but if you see the rest of the program if file John.txt doesnt exist the AI asks who is John and takes a different direction

Comment: @SoftwarePlayer, it appears that it just creates the file & then waits for another question (without answering the original question) if the file does not exist. Could you please explain what issue you are still having after these 2 solutions?